# node.js exported promise chain not running sequentially with web api callbacks

Tags: node.js, http, promise, callback, node-modules

I have 2 files. One (get_data.js) gets data from an API by getting an access token, using that to get the URL containing the data, then getting the csv data from that URL and converting it to JSON. 
The second file (process_data.js) just console.logs that JSON data.

Contents of get_data.js (in pseudo-code, as the file is quite long and the individual functions all work fine).

```
module.exports.getData = () => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(get_access_token());           // returns an access token from a web api
    })

    .then((access_token) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(get_url());                // returns a url from a web api
        })
    })

    .then((url) => {
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(get_data_from_url(url));    // returns a csv in a string from url
        })
    })

    .then((csv_data) => {
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(convert_csv_to_json());    // returns data in a json string
        })    
    })
}
```

Contents of process_data.js:

```
const dataHandler = require('./get_data');

dataHandler.getData()
.then(
    (JSON_data) => {
        console.log("JSON_data: ".concat(JSON_data))
    }
)
```

What I want to happen is

- run process_data.js
- it gets the data from get_data.js
- print that data to the console (for now)

However at the first API callback in get_data.js, the promise chain from process_data.js moves on and prints 'undefined', and I'm not sure why it's not waiting for the various callbacks from get_data.js. 
What's strange is that if I run get_data.js with a console.log(json_data) appended to the end of the code it all works fine. The problem is I need to be able to subdivide my code into modules.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Error printed to the console is below:

```
.then((JSON_data) => {console.log("JSON_data: ".concat(JSON_data))})
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tom/Desktop/stuff/process_data.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getData` you are currently not returning anything. That's why the error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` since returning nothing returns an `undefined`.

In order to `.then` on `dataHandler.getData()` you need to return your first `new Promise`.

```
module.exports.getData = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(get_access_token());           // returns an access token from a web api
    })

    .then((access_token) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(get_url());                // returns a url from a web api
        })
    })

    .then((url) => {
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(get_data_from_url(url));    // returns a csv in a string from url
        })
    })

    .then((csv_data) => {
        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(convert_csv_to_json());    // returns data in a json string
        })    
    })
}
```